# Unable to get php code to show a message before returning to header page

Tags: php, html

I've been having an issue getting php to show a message when a form is submitted via email.  I've googled it most of the day and tried a dozen or more fixes, but I cannot get it to show the message, it just jumps back to the previous page after execution, as per the header instructions in the php code.  Any ideas (not ajax please).

Here's the html that calls the php.

```
        <h2 class="u-text u-text-1">Questions or Comments?</h2>
        <div class="u-clearfix u-custom-html u-expanded-width u-custom-html-1">
          <form id="comment_form" action="form.php" method="post" style="none;width: 356px;padding: 10px;margin-top: 10px;float:top;margin-left: 40px;float: left;">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" name="email" size="40">
            <br>
            <br><!--       <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email" size="40"><br><br>  -->
            <textarea name="Name" placeholder="Name" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
            <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Comments" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <br>
            <br>
```

I know this has been asked millions of times, but nothing I've googled will work.

Here's the php.

```
<?php
        $email;$Name;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['Name'])){
          $name=$_POST['Name'];          
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $comment=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
      }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
    $secretKey = "--nope-not showing it--";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    // post request to server
    $url =  'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
    if($responseKeys["success"]) {
        $status = "Submission Successful";
//      echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment</h2>';
        $subject = "New Form Submission";
        $to = "admin@apt905.com";
        $comments = "name: $name \r\n email: $email \r\n $comment";
        $headers = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($to,$subject,$comments,$headers);
    } else {
        $status = "Submission Error";
//      echo '<h2>You are a spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        }
       
  if(isset($_REQUEST["destination"])){
      header("Location: {$_REQUEST["destination"]}");
  }else if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
      header("Location: {$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]}");
  }else{
       /* some fallback, maybe redirect to index.php */
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I will just assume, that problem is not because all `echo` is commented out and all conditions are working as expected.*

---

Since you can not use `header()` when there is output, you need to *first* set headers, and only then show text:

```php
header("refresh:5; url={$_REQUEST["destination"]}");

/* ... */

echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment</h2>';
```

This will start redirection after 5 seconds *and* only then show message (first process information and set message & url to use, then at the end set header and output message)

Comment: I just commented out the echo for testing, and all the conditions are working as expected.  When I use your code, it doesn't appear to go back to the calling page, but instead shows the "Thanks for posting comment" for 5 seconds, then shows echos "Please check the the captcha form.".  I'm not sure if it is going back and resubmitting or just rerunning the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, thanks Justinas.  I made a change in your header suggested statement to this and it works fine.

`header("refresh:5; url={$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");`